# why Gazebo crash while adding a 3D model? is a robotic arm .DAE

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to add in "model editor" (custom shapes) a model of a robotic arm but Gazebo crashes when I click in import. why this could happen? is there another way of loading the robotic arm? I tried also with .OBJ

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17567/why-gazebo-crash-while-adding-a-3d-model?-is-a-robotic-arm-.dae/) by [Jezel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3871/jezel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-10-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-10-18**:
When you run Gazebo in verbose mode, do you see any errors? (`gazebo --verbose`) I've seen Gazebo crash before with malforned collada files.

**Comment by [Jezel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3871/jezel/) on 2017-10-18**:
now I tried verbose mode and you are right, is not a valid collada.  "Invalid collada file. Must be version 1.4.0 or 1.4.1".

Thanks, i didn' t know about this verbose mode, at least now i know why is crashing. Is there any way to fix this colladas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As described on the comments, the issue is that the collada file is invalid.

One way around it would be to load it into a CAD program such as Blender and then re-export is as collada in the hope that the program will fix the issues.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jezel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3871/jezel/) on 2017-10-20**:
Got it, thanks a lot for your help